# Regex Expression HTML Grabbing C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

So I have a bunch of data that goes like this

```
<td class='Normal sItem' data-minwear='0.00' data-maxwear='1.00'
            data-search='AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge' data-name=
            'AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge' data-image=
            'http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz56P7fiDzRyTQXJVfdhX_ov5gnrDBgz5NNcWdKy_q4LZwm5toDOYrAuYdgYTcSEU_XQYAD84khqh6kLKsCAoy7r2nnoaGgLWhf1ujVTz27JTVE'
            data-category='Normal' data-quality='Covert' data-bestquality='10'
            data-exterior='Well-Worn' data-rawext='0' data-hashname='' data-custom=''
            data-inspect=''>
<td class='Normal sItem' data-minwear='0.00' data-maxwear='1.00'
            data-search='AK-47 | Elite Build' data-name='AK-47 | Elite Build'
            data-image=
            'http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz56P7fiDzRyTQXJVfdhUfQp4A3-EBg-4cBrQJnipOtTKgy95YaUM7J_Zd1PHpaDWv7VZA74vBo-0agJJ5Ld8Si8iyq8JC5UDD6vukmf'
            data-category='Normal' data-quality='Mil-Spec Grade' data-bestquality='4'
            data-exterior='Minimal Wear' data-rawext='0' data-hashname=''
            data-custom='' data-inspect=''>
```

I need to grab the variables and I've tried with regex but I'm finding it hard. Is regex the best way to do this? If someone could help me that would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to grab?

Comment: I want to grab everything, I want to kind of array and grab each td and then grab all of the variables. E.G data-minwear, data-search etc...

Comment: you need parsing. first make JSON string and then parse it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?